# How to optimize loading users in filter_horizontal in django admin

Tags: django

I have a `ManyToManyField` with `User` model.

In the `ModelAdmin`, I am populating users in `filter_horizontal`. However, it makes the loading very slow and even hangs the process if the number of users is large. This is because it fires individual queries to get information of each user.

Is there a way to optimize the loading process so that all the users can be loaded using a single queryset?

Comment: Firstly, try to accept more answers to your previous questions. It will give people incentive to help out. Regarding your question, you could use this library https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects and change the horizontal filters to ajax selects instead.

Comment: None of the answers to my previous questions helped. Hence I didn't accepted any.

Comment: Then post the solution you ended up using, or reply to incorrect answers.